How to construct std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<X>> from memory bloc created using mmap without copy
We are using boost::dynamic_bitset. We are looking for methods to construct std::vectorboost::dynamic_bitset<X> from memory bloc created using mmap without copy. Similarly we want to get memory buffer of uint_8 * from std::vectorboost::dynamic_bitset<X>

Can you use std::span or boost::span instead of std::vector? It's the best for non-owning views.

Do you need exactly std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<X>>, or would std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<X>, SomeAllocator> work for your purpose?

When you say we want to get memory buffer of uint_8 * do you realise that each element of the vector has it's own allocation, there is no single pointer to all the bits? Nor does boost promise that dynamic_bitset have a contiguous allocation of it's bits

boost::dynamic_bitset is not a trivial type (POD type), so you cannot just take a piece of memory and interpret it as a vector of such types.

Dynamic bitsets, as the name implies, are explicitly about bitsets that manage their own allocations.
However, since it is allocator aware you might make it allocate from shared memory. E.g. using boost interprocess:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

namespace Shared {
    using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    // using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file; // for COLIRU
    using Mgr     = Segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Mgr>;
    using BS                          = boost::dynamic_bitset<uint32_t, Alloc<uint32_t>>;
} // namespace Shared

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
static std::mt19937 prng{std::random_device{}()};

int main() {
    using namespace Shared;
    Segment shm(bip::open_or_create, "shared-demo", 10 << 10ull);
    BS&     bits = *shm.find_or_construct<BS>("bitset")(888, 0, shm.get_segment_manager());

    std::cout << "Bitset " << bits.count() << " / " << bits.size() << " set\n";
    auto dist = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, bits.size() - 1), ref(prng));

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { bits.set(dist()); }
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { bits.reset(dist()); }
}

Repeated runs show how it is persistent:

I'll leave inter-process synchronization (if required) as an exercise for the reader. Also, if you have to map from an unmanaged segment you might use managed_external_buffer. I have examples for both techniques on this site.
